# In PhpStorm, can Ctrl+Click go to class definition in PHP rather than the constructor?

Tags: phpstorm, code-navigation

I'm using PhpStorm and something that lately is bothering me a lot is this scenario. Suppose I have this setup:

```
// File1.php
abstract class AbstractBase {
    public function __construct() {
    }
}

// File2.php
class MyClass extends AbstractBase {
}

// File3.php
$var = new MyClass();
```

Now, if I'm reading the line if `File3.php` and want to go to `MyClass` definition if `File2.php`, the easiest way is to hold the Ctrl button and then click the `MyClass` name. This works very nicely for functions and member variables, and in PHPDoc comments, but in this case PhpStorm chooses to go to the constructor rather than the class definition. And since `MyClass` doesn't have a constructor of its own, it goes to the `AbstractBase` constructor in a completely different file.

I understand that in this case it's ambiguous what I want to do. I also  know that I can right-click `MyClass` and then select `Go To` and then `Type Declaration`. But is there a way to configure Ctrl-Click that it would go to the  class definition rather the constructor?

Comment: IDE version exactly? AFAIK it has been reverted back to initial behaviour in latest version. If not -- best workaround is to use shortcut for `Type Declaration` (you may assign mouse shortcut as well).

Comment: @LazyOne - Hey, you're right! I had 2018.1.1 installed, and after updating to 2018.1.3 it now does what I want. Thanks! :) That's what I get for putting off updates for too long. :D